# 読み込んだCSVファイルを購入日で3ヵ月毎に遡り、累計したデータを別々のCSVファイルとして出力したい

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

プログラミング初心者です。
読み込んだCSVファイルを購入日で3ヵ月毎に遡り、累計したデータを別々のCSVファイルとして出力したいです。
イメージとしては、
　ファイル1つ目：2020/01/01 - 2020/04/01
　ファイル2つ目：2020/01/01 - 2020/07/01
　ファイル3つ目：2020/01/01 - 2020/10/01
　など

エラーメッセージは出ないのですが、出力されるファイルがすべて同じ期間のものとなり
上記のような累計の形式にはなりません。
修正案をご教示いただけないでしょうか？

```
#結合したcsvファイルを読み込む
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/rfm/*.csv')

#購入日を計算可能なフォーマットを変換
df['購入日'] = pd.to_datetime(df['購入日'])

#3ヵ月毎でデータを分割し出力
dt_st = min(df['購入日']).to_pydatetime()
dt_ed = max(df['購入日']).to_pydatetime()

dt_cur = dt_st
while dt_cur < dt_ed:
    dt_cur = dt_cur + relativedelta(months=3)
    mask = (df['購入日'] >= dt_st) & (df['購入日'] <= dt_cur)
    grp = df.groupby(mask) 
    for g, df in grp:
        g = dt_cur.strftime('%Y%m%d')
        df.to_csv(f'/content/drive/MyDrive/rfm/rfm_until_{g}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: 「購入日」「3ヵ月毎に遡り」「累計」などの、対象・処理の内容や基準といったものの詳細が明確にはなっていないようです。それらを明確化して追記してみてください。その過程で自分で気付ける点もあるのでは？

Comment: おそらくマルチポスト [取得したCSVファイルを3ヵ月単位で遡って累計して別々のCSVファイルとして出力したい](https://teratail.com/questions/377578) そして関連記事 [取得したCSVファイルを3ヵ月単位で遡って別々のCSVファイルとして出力したい](https://teratail.com/questions/377010), [複数のCSVファイルを読み込み、それぞれのCSVファイルに対して同じ処理を行い、同じエクセルファイル内で別々のシートに出力したい](https://teratail.com/questions/uhay2s82ms97vc)

Answer (score 0):

[pandas.Grouper — pandas 1.3.5 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) を使うと良いかもしれません。

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''
購入日,データ
2020/1/1,a
2020/2/13,b
2020/3/26,c
2020/4/3,d
2020/5/17,e
2020/6/20,f
2020/7/8,g
2020/8/15,h
2020/9/22,i
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data), parse_dates=['購入日'])
(
  df.sort_values('購入日')
    .groupby(pd.Grouper(key='購入日', freq='3MS'))
    .apply(lambda x:
      x.to_csv(f'rfm_from_{x["購入日"].min().strftime("%Y%m%d")}_' +
               f'to_{x["購入日"].max().strftime("%Y%m%d")}.csv',
               index=False))
)
```

**実行後**

```sh
$ ls -1 *.csv
rfm_from_20200101_to_20200326.csv
rfm_from_20200403_to_20200620.csv
rfm_from_20200708_to_20200922.csv

$ for f in *.csv;do echo "$f"; cat $f; echo; done
rfm_from_20200101_to_20200326.csv
購入日,データ
2020-01-01,a
2020-02-13,b
2020-03-26,c

rfm_from_20200403_to_20200620.csv
購入日,データ
2020-04-03,d
2020-05-17,e
2020-06-20,f

rfm_from_20200708_to_20200922.csv
購入日,データ
2020-07-08,g
2020-08-15,h
2020-09-22,i
```